# Does yarn add package --build-from-source behave like npm install package --build-from-source when passing node-gyp flags to packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, yarnpkg

It looks like `yarn` does not pass node-gyp flags to native packages the way `npm` does.

For example when attempting to install sqlite3@3.1.6 with:

```
npm install sqlite3@3.1.6 \
  --build-from-source \
  --sqlite_libname=sqlcipher \
  --sqlite=`brew --prefix` \
  --verbose
```

we get a successful installation of sqlite3 with sqlcipher extensions, due to passing `--sqlite_libname` and `--sqlite`, which are [specified](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/blob/d18c1e97de9478aab27067638899b068e6d8ed03/binding.gyp#L3) in sqlite3's `binding.gyp`.

But, when attempting to use `yarn`, and running what I would think to be the equivalent command, it looks like the flags aren't honored:

```
yarn add sqlite3@3.1.6 \
  --force \
  --build-from-source \
  --sqlite_libname=sqlcipher \
  --sqlite=`brew --prefix` \
  --verbose
```

With `npm` unrecognized command line arguments are converted to gyp flags.

With `yarn` that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to get this functionality with `yarn`?

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfy your question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is currently possible by using environment variables on the format `npm_config_{snake_case_param}=true/false`

For example, `npm install --build-from-source=true` becomes:

```
npm_config_build_from_source=true yarn install
```

It's documented here https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/envvars/#toc-npm-config

Answer (score 2):

Yarn does not automatically expose `--` arguments of install command to lifecycle scripts (pre/post/install scripts in package.json of dependencies).
Here is the code where Yarn builds Env for the script execution https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/src/util/execute-lifecycle-script.js#L39.

You can pass specific values via `env` setting in .yarnrc and also it builds `npm_config_*` settings based on .yarnrc/.npmrc configuration.

Comment: Can you give an example? The .yarnrc file doesn't seem to be documented very well on yarn's website.

Comment: .yarnrc uses the same parser for yarn.lock files, very similar to yaml files.
You can add an env section to .yarnrc

    env:
      ENV_PARAM "value"
      ENV_PARAM_2 "value2"


Give this a try and if it works please contribute to the docs, most of it is done by the community and is very much appreciated https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarnrc

Comment: But these aren't environmental variables as far as I know. They are command line parameters passed to the install scripts.