Botpress v12 Dependencies Incompatible with Node Version
I am trying to set up the botpress v12 repo on my local machine.
I am facing issues during dependency resolution
This is my environment
OS: MacOS 15.1
Chip: Apple M2 Pro

Terminal: iTerm2 (arch: arm64) (Not using rosetta)
brew: 4.4.4
nvm: 0.39.7 (installed using brew)
node: v12.22.12 (installed using nvm)
npm: 6.14.16
yarn: 1.22.22 (installed using npm as a global dependency)

When i ran the following command
$ yarn && yarn build

The error I am facing is
error @jest/types@29.6.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0". Got "12.22.12"
error Found an incompatible module.

In package.json, the node engine is configured to ^12
I added a resolution to the package.json to use earlier versions of @jest/types
but it's continuously showing errors like this for other dependencies.
I tried adding more resolutions to the package.json until the dependency installation was successful, but it failed when I tried to build the project.
Solutions Tried & Failed
Ignoring Node Engines
I tried running the yarn command while ignoring the node engines as suggested by Estus Flask
yarn --ignore-engines
I faced the following issues at the build stage
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/----/work/----/----/botpress/node_modules/sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/phani/work/itac/----/botpress/node_modules/sqlite3
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@22.11.0 | darwin | arm64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
(node:94500) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/phani/work/itac/kankabot/botpress/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v127-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v127-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v127-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v127-darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@22.11.0 (node-v127 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v127-darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with an ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@22.11.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with an ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@22.11.0 | darwin | arm64

It looks like one of the optional dependencies, sqlite3 has no pre-built binaries for node 22.

Update Node version to the latest even versions, 22 or 20. This shouldn't be a problem since nvm is used. Make sure the dependencies were completely reinstalled because they may depend on Node version.
There's no fundamental problem with this error as it's basically a warning that can be ignored. That it's an error will likely make && to not work, so you can ignore engines in Yarn.
The potential problem is you have node version that is very stale (5y old) and packages can have real errors with it. This wasn't explained:

it's failing at the compileTyepscript stage

But it's safe to assume this was the real error.

I've run the yarn --ignore-engines command with the latest node version: 22.11.0
But it didn't work. I got errors during the build stage. I updated my original question with the tried approach and the errors I faced.

yarn --ignore-engines makes sense only for node 12 and "The engine "node" is incompatible", which is a symptom of a more serious problem. Try v20 as suggested, it has a better chance than 22 regarding bins, but as I can see, the problem is not incompatibility but that sqlite screwed up the storage for prebuilt deps (that's what 403 means in the log), see https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/issues/1389 and https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/issues/1421

If the problem is the same with 20, which is expected, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368337/3731501 , the machine should be configured correctly to build bin deps.
